# Facebook app on users timeline

Tags: facebook

i have been searching the for an answer how to make app show up on users timeline in facebook. I have tried making my application into other types and stuff, but sadly it did not help. I know some apps did such thing but i seem can not find a solution for it. It should be displayed here (as shown in screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know anyone have any ideas how to do it? Or atleast how this feature is/was called?

Comment: I think Facebook has removed that feature again.

Comment: But some apps still have that feature. Doesn't removal of that feature should remove the current ones too?

Comment: Also how this feature was/is called? i can't seem find the right name for it.

Comment: Facebook occasionally keeps such features working for apps that had already implemented them, while not allowing any new apps to implement them.

Comment: @CBroe If i were to get a old application (that was created a year or two ago) i still might be able to use this feature? or no? what do you think?

Comment: I doubt it. Best if you just forget that this feature even existed once. Make do with what is currently possible and officially documented.